# How to change the text color of disabled Asp.net DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I searched for some time on this question and couldn't find a working answer anywhere.

I have an asp DropDownList that gets disabled and enabled based on whether the form is in view mode or not. The problem I was having is when the DropDownList.Enabled = false the text is hard to read(grey on lightgrey).

I solved the issue by passing the DropDownList to some methods.

```
public void DisableDDL(ref DropDownList DDL)
{
    DDL.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
    foreach (ListItem i in DDL.Items)
    {
        if (i != DDL.SelectedItem)
        {
            i.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

public void EnableDDL(ref DropDownList DDL)
{
    DDL.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    foreach (ListItem i in DDL.Items)
    {
        i.Enabled = true;                        
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do this?
I tried using css but that didn't work.

```
<style>
.disabledStyle
{
    color: black;        
}
</style>

myDDl.CssClass = "disabledStyle";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no readonly property for the dropdownlist control. But you can move the focus to another control when it receives the focus and that will prevent it from being changed and leave the text black.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the style to each individual ListItem, and not to the DropDownList itself

Comment: That sounds very tedious, I have about 15 DDLs to enable/disable.

Comment: Create a helper method. Pass in a DropDownList object. Iterate against it: foreach Item in ListItems{ Item.CssClass = "aspNetDisabled"; }

Comment: Item doesn't seem to have that as a property. If I go into Item.Attributes there is a CssStyle attribute but it is {get} only.

Comment: There might be an `Attributes.Add` property that you can use to assign a css class to the object.  EDIT: I'm more of a VB.NET guy, but this should be as simple as something along the lines of `itemname.Attributes.Add("style", ".disabledStyle");` or so as you're iterating through the list of items in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I have just put in a dropdownlist and put it to enabled false in the controller, then I found out that it has a class called "aspNetDisabled", I have tried to use CSS to change color on it, it works perfectly.

```
<style>
    .aspNetDisabled 
    {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

In the code, if you put the dropdownlist, "ddl.enabled = false", it will be like this:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled"></select>
```

If the dropdownlists are surrounded by a div with a class, use the class to define the disabled ones:

```
<style>
    .MyCssClass[disabled] 
    {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

Or try

```
:disabled,[disabled]
{
    -ms-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity:0.5;
}
</style>
```

As said in here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/2028164.aspx?IE+11+disabled+buttons+links+not+shown+as+greyed+out

Comment: This works running IE11 from localhost and in chrome from the host server, but when I try it in IE11 from the host server it still shows as grey on grey.

Comment: Still didn't work. Thank you for all the help though. I will just keep my current workaround.

Comment: I found a better solution. Instead of changing the text color I changed the background color.    'select[disabled] { background-color: white; }'

Comment: However, now it looks weird on chrome with everything else grey background black text and the DropDownLists white with black text...

Comment: On my website, i have just put "opacity" to "0.5" on the class "form-control", which is all form controls.. but i have only dropdownlists is disabled.. and i like that..

Comment: a while back [disabled] seemed flaky with the browser support at the time. It was 3/4 years ago so it may be more fully supported now...

Comment: I am using Resharper, and it is helping me to put vendor-specific properties, when i use opacity: 0.5 it adds -ms-opacity: 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that:

```
<style>
    [disabled] { /* Text and background colour, medium red on light yellow */
    color:#933;
    background-color:#ffc;
    }

    </style>
```